# How to show this equality from the Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis, probability-distributions, cauchy-integral-formula

In a paper https://projecteuclid.org/journals/brazilian-journal-of-probability-and-statistics/volume-36/issue-2/Limit-theorems-for-quasi-arithmetic-means-of-random-variables-with/10.1214/22-BJPS531.short , the author said that if $X$ has Cauchy distribution, $$\lim_{R\to \infty}\frac{1}{R}\sup_{|z|=R}|f(z)|=0, \quad (1)$$ $$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\varepsilon\sup_{|z-a|=\varepsilon}|f(z)|=0,\quad (2)$$ then $E(f(X))=f(\mu +\sigma i)$.

I tried to show the above statement but I couldn't.

My try: Since $X$ has Cauchy distribution, we have $$E[f(X)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)(\frac{\sigma}{\pi}\frac{1}{(x-\mu)^2+\sigma^2})dx$$ $$=\frac{\sigma}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x)}{(x-\mu)^2+\sigma^2}dx$$ $$=\frac{\sigma}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{2i\sigma}(\frac{f(x)}{x-\mu-i\sigma}-\frac{f(x)}{x-\mu+i\sigma})dx$$ $$=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x)}{x-\mu-i\sigma}dx -\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x)}{x-\mu+i\sigma}dx=f(\mu+\sigma i).$$

The author says that the result follows from the Cauchy integral formula, due to
(1) and (2) But I didn't use (1) and (2). Is there something wrong in my proof? I'd really appreciate if someone could help me about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without (1), $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)/(x-\mu-i\sigma) dx$ may actually diverge. If you apply Cauchy's integral formula rigorously, you will find that (1) needed here. The condition (2) will probably occur in your rigorous use of the integral formula, even though I am not sure what the $a$ there is.

Comment: @flowing Thank you so much for your explanation. I understood well. Appreciate it.